# Using PHP script from web server to access GPIO pins on RPI and execute GPIO commands at a specific time

Tags: php, bash, raspberry-pi3, chatbot

I am using DialogFlow to create a chatbot and I have connected it to a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Vi.2. DialogFlow sends an action which index.php on the Pi uses a switch-case statement to decide what action to take. I would like it to access the GPIO pins at specific times though which is where I am having difficulties. An example is shown below:

```
switch ($action) {
    case "kitchenOn":
        echo shell_exec('sh script.sh');
            sendMessage(array(
                "source" => $update["result"]["source"],
                "speech" => "Kitchen light: on",
                "displayText" => "Hello from",
                "contextOut" => array()
            ));
            break;
}
```

The file "script.sh" contains the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "gpio -1 mode 7 out" | at 20:00
echo "gpio -1 write 7 1" | at 20:00
```

The script works when I run it directly from my Pi but not when executed from the PHP script. Can anybody tell me why this is?

Many thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have used exec() and the exit code prints:

```
sh:0: Can't open script2.sh
```

The script file is in the home directory so it should point straight to it, any ideas?

Comment: switch to [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and check the `exit code`

Comment: I have tried exec(), still not working, how do you check the exit code?

Comment: `exec($command, $output, $return); var_dump($return, $output);` -  with `$return` being the exit code